# Unrecognized name when using field filters in Metabase with Google BigQuery as source database

Tags: google-bigquery, field, metabase

I am facing an issue when using `WITH AS` in combination with field filters in Metabase. Running this query 1)

```
WITH temp AS
    (SELECT col_a FROM `dataset_name`.`table_name`)
SELECT col_a
FROM temp
WHERE {{col_a}}
```

raises the issue

```
Unrecognized name: `dataset_name.table_name`
```

If I execute this query directly in BigQuery and exchange the curly brackets with an IN statement by myself, it works

```
WITH temp AS
    (SELECT col_a FROM `dataset_name`.`table_name`)
SELECT col_a
FROM temp
WHERE `temp`.`col_a` IN ("value_a")
```

but somehow Metabase translates query 1) to

```
WITH temp AS
    (SELECT * FROM `dataset_name`.`table_name`)
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE `dataset_name`.`table_name`.`col_a` in ("value_a")
```

and claims to not be able to find `` dataset_name`.`table_name ``.

Do you have any clue how I am able to use field filters in combination with the `WITH AS` statement?

Comment: Hi, does my answer help with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, you can employ WITH and field filters together as follows:

```
WITH temp AS ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_stations`
    )
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE station_id > 1000
```